# decidePolicyForNavigationAction error only upon first launch IPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Sorry, I'm new in iOS development and currently working in a project with legacy errors.

When app first launch on IPad the webview won't show up if user input to open an ebook, trowing the following error.

webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument

I managed to debug the code until the function below is called. Self is the EbookViewController containing all the right data needed.

[self becomeFirstResponder];

I don't understand how the becomeFirstResponder and the error Threw are related. 
I might guess that the becomeFirstResponder is not really working.

Am I in the right direction? What could be this "nil argument"? I'm confused because it happens only in iPad upon first launch

Answer (score 0):

After search everywhere, I managed to destroy the first webview generate and create a new one with the same characteristics. It worked!!